# Django-Nonrel(mongo-backend):Model instance modification tracking

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-models, django-nonrel

I am using Django non-rel version with mongodb backends. I am interested in tracking the changes that occur on model instances e.g if someone creates/edits or deletes a model instance. Backend db is mongo hence models have an associated "_id" fields with them in the respective collections/dbs.

Now i want to extract this "_id" field on which this modif operation took place. The idea is to write this "_id" field to another db so someone can pick it up from there and know what object was updated.

I thought about overriding the **save()** method from Django **"models.Model"** since all my models are derived from that. However the mongo "_id" field is obviously not present there since the mongo-insert has not taken place yet.

Is there any possibility of a pseudo **post-save()** method that can be called after the save operation has taken place into mongo? Can django/django-toolbox/pymongo provide such a combination?

Comment: So, do you want to track the changes on the object or just the timestamp when the object was saved?

Comment: I want to track the object id "_id" for the modified object. So that i  can send it to some other process etc so it knows what was updated. Not anything specific to timestamp. My other process can update itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some deep digging into the Django Models i was able to solve the problem. The **save()** method inturn call the **save_base()** method. This method saves the returned results, ids in case of mongo, into **self.id**. This **_id** field can then be picked by by over riding the **save()** method for the model